# How to compute Jacobian of unrolled RNN states with Tensorflow eager execution

Tags: tensorflow

If we represent unrolled RNN as follows

`final_state, output = Unroll_RNN_10_Steps(initial_state, input)`

How can one compute the Jacobian of `final_state` with respect to `initial_state`?

Answer (score 1):

Faster ways of doing this are being worked on, but as of TF 1.5 here is some sample code:

```
batch_size = 2
steps = 10
units = 3

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(units)
initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
inputs = [tf.random_uniform([batch_size, units]) for _ in
          range(steps)]

with tf.contrib.eager.GradientTape(persistent=True) as g:
  g.watch(initial_state.c)
  state = initial_state
  for i in range(steps):
    _, state = cell(inputs[i], state)
  # Split the final state into scalar tensors
  # so that we can compute gradients with respect to each
  # scalar below.
  states = tf.split(state.c, units, axis=1)

# Compute the gradients of each scalar in the final state
# with respect to initial state for each example in the batch.
# Each element in grads has shape [batch_size, units]
grads = [g.gradient(states[i], [initial_state.c])[0]
         for i in range(units)]
# Stack grads so that their shape is [units, batch_size, units]
grads = tf.stack(grads)
# reshape grads to [batch_size, units, units] so that
# jacobian[b, :, :] is the Jacobian of b'th example in the batch
jacobian = tf.transpose(grads, perm=[1, 0, 2])
print("Jacobian shape: " + str(jacobian.shape))
```

Comment: I have done this in tf2.0 but I am not sure about the shape of the Jacobian gradient. For initial hidden state h0 shaped (batch_size, n_units), hidden states at step t ht shaped (batch_size, n_steps, n_units), I got the gradient dht/dh0 with shape (batch_size, n_units). Is that right? I was expecting the object to have n_steps as an index